# Refactoring a collection of if statements that contain 2 arguments.

Tags: c#

At the moment I have seven if statements that resemble the following code:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour1" && start_time > look_at_time)
        {
            new_colour1.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);

            var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
            foreach( GameObject c in colums)
                c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = new_colour1.orignalMaterial;
        }


        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour2" && start_time > look_at_time)
        {

            new_colour2.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);
            var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
            foreach( GameObject c in colums)
                c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = new_colour2.orignalMaterial;
        }
```

Each statement is roughly 6 lines of code and takes up a lot of space and can be a little tricky to read. What I'm wanting to do is find a way to re factor this so that my code is little less clunky and doesn't take up too much space.

I had thought about changing my collection of if statements into a switch statement but I discovered that switch statements can't handle two arguments like I have above. If there any other way I can re factor my code but keep the same functionality or am I stuck with my collection of if statements?

Comment: The only thing different in the bodies of the if statements is the new_colour1/new_colour2 object.  If you made a helper function that took hit.collider.gameObject.tag and returned the appropriate object, you could pass that object to a function defined by the stuff in the bodies of the if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start looking at what is duplicated.  For example, the only difference between the two blocks of code is the string `"Color1"` and `"Color2"` in the if statement, and the variable `new_colour1` which is replaced with `new_colour2`.

From here I'd suggest something like the following:

```
//This should be declared once - e.g. class level not method level.
var colorDict = new Dictionary<string, NewColorType> 
                    {
                        {"Colour1", new_colour1}, 
                        {"Colour2", new_colour2}
                    };
NewColorType newColor;
if(start_time > look_at_time && colorDict.TryGetValue(hit.collider.gameObject.tag, out newColor))
{
   newColor.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);
   var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
   foreach( GameObject c in colums)
      c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = newColor.orignalMaterial;
}
```